# How can I map a map that includes special characters in vim (e.g. <cr> or <esc>)?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to map the enter key in Vim the *first* time to create a sort of... pre-mapping.

This is basically want I want:

```
nnoremap <cr> :nnoremap <cr>:!tmux send-keys -t :1.0 "py.test --cov" C-m <cr><cr>
```

But I want all of the `<cr>` (except the first one) to literally be like I typed <kbd><</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>></kbd>. I won't know ahead of time what tmux session:window.pane I want to send these keys to, but I don't want to have to type out that whole thing. The first time I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> I want it to all pop up ready for me to just move over to the right stuff, set my session, window, and pane, and just hit enter.

But right now it's treating the others as command characters. What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `<lt>` to replace the first `<` in each of the keys. So the command would be

```
nnoremap <cr> :nnoremap <lt>cr>:!tmux send-keys -t :1.0 "py.test --cov" C-m <lt>cr><lt>cr>
```

Comment: I *knew* there was a right way to do this. Just couldn't remember what it was. Apparently I've been up too long.

Answer (score 0):

One (likely) horrible solution is

```
c<left><<right><right>r>
```